# SSO using Active Directory and Disabled Accounts

Tags: active-directory, single-sign-on

We are integrating our company with third party tool for personnel management and will be using Active Directory for SSO.  We need terminated employees to be able to login to this third party tool to retrieve things like W-2s, but disabling them in AD when they are terminated seems to prevent this.  What is the best practice for this?  How can we continue to use AD for SSO without leaving terminated employees active in AD (even if they're in a restricted OU)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they need to authenticate against the domain, you can't disable the account. However, you can restrict where they can login.

There is this setting which denies "log on locally" (i.e. they cannot log in interactively to any computer): https://4sysops.com/archives/deny-and-allow-workstation-logons-with-group-policy/

But logging in remotely anywhere still may be too open for you.

There is also the 'Log On To' settings on each account. In AD Users and Computers, on the Account tab of a User object, there is a 'Log On To' button. There you can specify if the user can login to 'All computers' or only certain ones. You may be able to use that and add only the server names of the applications they need to access.

I've never personally used that feature before, so you might have to play around with it to make it work. There is probably a way to set it in group policy too, if you want to apply it to a whole OU of users.